# MySQL how to update 325 matches inside table in one go?

Tags: mysql, database

Hi all :) I'm trying to figure out how I can update in bulk content of the table. Search for "domain.com returns:

```
325 match(es) inside table uk_articles
```

I need to update all 325 matches for domain.com with newdomain.com in table uk_articles. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: MySQL has an [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) command.  Have you tried it?  If so, did you get errors?  What were they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL update command is what you are looking for. This will get it done.

```
update `your table name` set your_column_name = 'newdomain.com' where your_column_name = 'domain.com'
```

replace your table name and column name with actual values, along with the domain names.

Comment: If you indent your code by 4 spaces, Len_D, then it will be formatted like code.  Also, always good to have something other than just a line of code (e.g. an explanation) as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyMiller. I'm still a relative newbie here and sometimes I just go from my head to the keyboard without filters :-)

Comment: No problem.  I see your edit, now with 4 spaces in front of "update", you'll be all good. (And, I *still* consider myself a noob here!)